# async for loop causes the function to silently terminate

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello I'm trying to understand what is going on in the following piece of code:

```js
import fs from "fs";
import util from "util";
import split2 from "split2";

async function main() {
    const files = await fs.promises.readdir("..");
    for (const f of files) {
        const s = fs.createReadStream("../" + f);
        const ss = s.pipe(split2());
        s.on("error", (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
        for await (const l of ss) {
        }

        console.log(f);
    }
    console.log("Returning");
    return "Done";
}
main();
```

It basically reads every file in a directory and iterates over the lines of each file (by using for await syntax for a readable stream piped into split2 library. The problem is that when the file is indeed a directory the createReadStream fails (and subsequently nothing is piped in downstreams). Weirdly it seems that a single error is causing the main function to silently exit and showing just few filenames before the error.

```html
.gitignore
app.js
[Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read] {
  errno: -21,
  code: 'EISDIR',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

If I just comment the await for loop instead I have the following output.

```html
.gitignore
app.js
business
components
config
env.skeletron
node_modules
package-lock.json
Returning
[Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read] {
  errno: -21,
  code: 'EISDIR',
  syscall: 'read'
}
[Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read] {
  errno: -21,
  code: 'EISDIR',
  syscall: 'read'
}
[Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read] {
  errno: -21,
  code: 'EISDIR',
  syscall: 'read'
}
[Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read] {
  errno: -21,
  code: 'EISDIR',
  syscall: 'read'
}
[Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read] {
  errno: -21,
  code: 'EISDIR',
  syscall: 'read'
}
[Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read] {
  errno: -21,
  code: 'EISDIR',
  syscall: 'read'
}
[Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read] {
  errno: -21,
  code: 'EISDIR',
  syscall: 'read'
}
[Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read] {
  errno: -21,
  code: 'EISDIR',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

This is indeed the full list of files and the individual errors are not stopping the outer loop. I'm running this with node v14.0.0 on an Ubuntu machine. Any idea of what is going on? I'm really lost :-D

Comment: Do you also have directories inside of this folder? For example a `node_modules` directory?

Comment: @ChrisG yes, in fact it is shown in the second run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't handling errors on the `for await (const l of ss) {...}` loop.  When you try to run this on a directory, your `for await` loop will reject and since you don't catch or handle that rejection, the containing `async` function will also reject and the program will stop.

You can try putting a try/catch around the `for await` loop and see if that works.  But, I've found numerous bugs in the `for await` feature with streams and even filed some of the bugs.  The bugs occur if there are errors opening the file or errors reading the file so this feature is just buggy and I've decided not to use it in my code for this reason.

Also, note that you don't have a good way to communicate back errors from the `error` event since you can't reject the `async` function from inside that nested event handler.  Overall streams and their events do not mix very well with promise-based programming.  There are ways to promisify some of the stream events, but it's a work-in-progress to make streams work well with promises.

Comment: Yes I tried to catch the errors but indeed it didn't work; I was in fact thinking of some bugs in the implementation but I was hoping that was just my fault:-) Can you point me out some of the bugs you filed? Thank you

Comment: @FulvioD'Antonio - Here's one: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/30831

Comment: Thank you, I think I am also going to avoid using this feature even if it seemed very handy...

Comment: @FulvioD'Antonio - Here's another related bug (that I didn't file): https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/31603.

Comment: Ok, now I have definitely a better idea of what is happening....thank you

Comment: @FulvioD'Antonio - Since it looks like you may be new here, if this information provided you with an answer to your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark next to this answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.

Comment: yes I will do it soon, I was just waiting for any additional follow up:-)